# I want to add two numbers in A.java and print the result in B.java ( How? )

Tags: java, object

I want to add two numbers in A.java and print the result in B.java ( How? )

### A.java

```
class A {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       int x= 5;
       int y = 8; 
   }

    void Sum() {
        z = x+y;
    }
}
```

### B.java

```
class B {
    A obj = new A();
    System.out.println("Result= "A.Sum());
}
```

---

I'm not able to solve this. 
Please help me .. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pass a reference to instance of A to a method on an instance of B or vice-versa.

Comment: Note that your "class B" isn't legal JSON.

Comment: I would suggest to start with Java basics. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138747.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something more like this:

A.java

```
class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    public A (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    }

    public int sum() {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

B.java

```
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A(5, 8);
        System.out.println("Result=" + obj.sum());
    }
}
```

Since you are instantiating `A`, it doesn't need a `main` it needs a constructor to set the values. It does not need to take parameters as I have written it, you could just set them in the constructor to some hard coded value if you like. `B` needs a `main` method the way it is as I'm assuming you're going to be running it? If not, you can change that to a constructor to be called from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks your program is perfectly running.
But the thing is I want to declare the method in main function and print the output in B.Java.
A.Java will contain main function and the method Sum 
B.Java will print the result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the `sum()` method to be in `B.java`, and the `main()` method to be in `A.java`?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a difficult concept for many newbies to grasp.  When you say `new SomeClass()` you create an "instance" of the class, and returned "reference" to that instance can be uses as it's "handle" to pass access from place to place.

So, in A's `main` you might do

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.doSomething(a);
```

In B you might have a method

```
public void doSomething(A aRef) {
    int result = aRef.sum();
    System.out.println("The answer is " + result);
}
```

Then back in A, the `sum` method

```
 public int sum() {
     return x + y;
 }
```

But we haven't defined or given values to x and y yet, so first insert the declarations in A, outside of any method (generally ahead of the first method) --

```
 int x;
 int y;
```

You could assign their values there, but it's more "realistic" to assign them dynamically.  In `main`, after doing `new A` but before calling `doSomething`

```
 a.x = 5;
 a.y = 8;
```

Note that you must supply the `a.` because `main` is static and hence does not have automatic addressability to instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors here. Here is the corrected class A with comments:

```
class A {

    int x= 5;  //x and y must be declared here, as instance variables (not local variables in main)
    int y = 8; 

    public static void main(String args[]) { //you don't need a main method here

    }

    public int Sum() {  //you need to return an int here
        return(x+y);
    }
}
```

And here is the corrected class B:

```
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();  //these two statements must be inside main()
                          //if you want them to execute
        System.out.println("Result= " + obj.Sum()); //use the object you created
                                                    //to call Sum()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems to your code

1)  In Class B you instantiate obj of class A but then use the class `A.Sum()`  This should be

```
 A obj = new A();
 System.out.println("Result= " + obj.Sum());
```

2)  In your class A you have the variables `x` and `y` in the main method (which isnt used).  These need to be class variables

```
public class A{

int x= 5;
int y = 8; 

public void Sum() 
}
```

Also,  The scope of these classes may need to be public

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem in OOP you can solve like this

A.java

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new B().print();        
    }

    public static int sum(int... values) {
        int total=0;
        for(int num: values){
            total+=num;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

B.java

```
public class B {

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Result= "+A.sum(4,2));
    }
}
```